# Why can't I add this to machine.config

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, machine.config

I would like to add this section to my machine.config in exactly the same way many articles and microsoft are suggesting:

```
  <configuration>
    <system.net>
       <connectionManagement>
         <add name = "www.contoso.com" maxconnection = "4" />
         <add name = "*" maxconnection = "2" />
       </connectionManagement>
     </system.net>
 </configuration>
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903351(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903351%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)
http://geekswithblogs.net/StuartBrierley/archive/2009/09/30/tuning-iis---machine.config-settings.aspx

As soon as I do it though, I get this exception when trying to hit a page hosted on the IIS on the same machine:

> Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section system.net.
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 9:      settings that differ from their defaults.
> Line 10: --><configuration>
> Line 11:  <system.net>
> Line 12:          <connectionManagement>
> Line 13:              <add address="*" maxconnection="24" />
> ```
>
> Source File: 
>   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config
>
> Line: 11

Where is the problem and how can I modify the machine.config so that I can finally control the `maxconnection` value?

Comment: You should mark an answer has accepted even if it's yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my machine.config line 10 is still part of the opening comments.  Did you delete those?

the --> suggests you may not have deleted the closing xml comment, or you may have accidentally deleted the opening xml comment token.  Make sure you have the opening `<!--`

EDIT:

Do you have the opening xml header?  the fact the line numbers are off seems odd to me.  Line 9 should be one line higher up.
Here's what it should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Please refer to machine.config.comments for a description and
    the default values of each configuration section.

    For a full documentation of the schema please refer to
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=42127

    To improve performance, machine.config should contain only those
    settings that differ from their defaults.
-->
```

Comment: No I have doubled checked the commented out portion. It's all in tact. The issue appears to be in adding the above mentioned <system.net> ... stuff

Answer (score 1):

The resolution was to move the  config section **after** this line in the config file:

```
  <sectionGroup name="system.net" type="System.Net.Configuration.NetSectionGroup, ...
```

That seem to help tha matters.

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding the XML in your question to the config file as-is, that's a problem.

`configuration` should be the (single) root element, you should add `system.net` under that if it doesn't exist - under `configuration`.

If it does exist, add the `connectionManagement` section in the existing `system.net` section.

If *that* already exists, add or modifify the existing `add` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you're not adding the `system.net` section before the [`configSections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228256.aspx) element.

The `configSections` element if present in the configuration file must the first child of `configuration` and in machine.config you should have `configSections` element defined.

---

*Disclaimer:* I answered the question without realizing that it was already asked eight months ago and that the OP had already found a solution to the problem. Since his answer gives a solution without explaining why, I decided not to delete my answer, and now I have a disclaimer that's bigger than the answer... I should really start to pay more attention.